# Set ActiveMQ message header while using Camel's @Produce annotation

Tags: header, activemq-classic, apache-camel

We are using Camel to send messages via ActiveMQ.  In our code, we have the following configuration, it works:

```
@Produce(uri = IEventService.QUEUE_NAME)
private IProducer sender;

@Override
public void emit(final Event e) {
    sender.emit(e);
}
```

Now, we want to use ActiveMQ Message Groups:
http://activemq.apache.org/message-groups.html

According to the documentation, I need to set JMSXGroupID in the message header.  How do I get at the message header so that I can set this property in my emit() api?

Thanks.
-AP_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of annotating @Produce to a IProducer (which you defined yourself, right?), you could do

```
@EndpointInject(uri = IEventService.QUEUE_NAME)
private ProducerTemplate sender;

@Override
public void emit(final Event e){
   sender.sendBodyAndHeader(e,"JMSXGroupID",someId);
}
```

Not sure if this is ok though, or if you are using IProducer for something else.

Comment: Yes using the ProducerTemplate allows to send headers as well. We could consider with the proxy thingy eg @Produce on interface, to have 2nd+ parameters as headers. And if you pass in a Map then its a map of headers.

Comment: I logged a ticket to get this improved: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6007

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to send to a direct:myname endpoint. Then you have a small route from("direct:myname").to(IEventService.QUEUE_NAME)

So in this route you can easily add headers.